# Writetable is exporting data with "Nullable{Type}(data)" instead of just data in Julia

Tags: dataframe, export, julia

For example, I have a DataFrame like the one seen below, let's call it df.

```
╔═════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ Row ║ a    ║ b    ║ c    ║
╠═════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ 1   ║ 0.66 ║ 0.55 ║ 0.44 ║
╠═════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ 2   ║ 0.11 ║ 0.22 ║ 0.33 ║
╠═════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ 3   ║ 1.00 ║ 2.00 ║ 3.00 ║
╚═════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

When I use writetable("output.txt",df) I receive the following type of output for the numerical data in the text file.

> "Nullable{Float64}(0.66)"

instead of

> 0.66

Any thoughts on how to get writetable to export just the data?

EDIT:

I should note that this only occurs after importing data using the ReadStat package. Is it possible to convert an entire data set to just an Array that can be exported properly? That may solve the problem.

EDIT #2:

I just tried running the following code (utilizing a created function `converter`) but am receiving errors (posted below).

```
f(a,n)=
    if typeof(a[n])==NullableArrays.NullableArray{String,1}
    convert(Array{String},a[n])
elseif typeof(a[n])==NullableArrays.NullableArray{Float64,1}
    convert(Array{Float64},a[n])
elseif typeof(a[n])==NullableArrays.NullableArray{Int64,1}
    convert(Array{Float64},a[n])
end
```

`converter(a)=hcat([f(a,n) for n=1:length(a)]...)`

The errors received are as follows:

```
julia> converter(af)
ERROR: NullException()
 in convert at /home/ale/.julia/v0.5/NullableArrays/src/primitives.jl:248 [inlined]
 in convert(::Type{Array{Float64,N}}, ::NullableArrays.NullableArray{Float64,1}) at /home/ale/.julia/v0.5/NullableArrays/src/primitives.jl:256
 in f(::DataFrames.DataFrame, ::Int64) at ./REPL[6]:5
 in collect_to!(::Array{Array{T,1},1}, ::Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},##1#2{DataFrames.DataFrame}}, ::Int64, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:340
 in collect_to!(::Array{Array{Float64,1},1}, ::Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},##1#2{DataFrames.DataFrame}}, ::Int64, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:350
 in collect(::Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},##1#2{DataFrames.DataFrame}}) at ./array.jl:308
 in converter(::DataFrames.DataFrame) at ./REPL[7]:1
```

Comment: not sure how ReadStat changes things, but you could try getting your columns and converting them to normal float arrays: `convert(Array{Float64}, df[:a])` and / or possibly recreating your DataFrame using these normal arrays. But yes, if I just create a normal dataframe with the above contents and write it out with `writetable`, output seems fine.

Comment: I think I have discovered the problem. Since ReadStat uses the Nullable Arrays package, it replaces Null values with #NULL. These values cannot be converted. The converter function I posted above works until I reach columns where #NULL values exist. I'll see if I can find a way to replace these with something that can be converted to either a value or just NA. I tried `replace(af[338],#NULL,NA)` where 338 is the column where `#NULL` first appears but I can not execute the code due to the `#`.

Comment: ah, I see. `#NULL` is just for visual representation. The actual value is `Nullable{Float64}()`. If you do `a = Nullable{Float64}()` you'll see that `a.hasvalue` is false. As opposed to say `a = Nullable{Float64}(1.0)` where `a.hasvalue` is true and `a.value` is `1.0`.  I'm not familiar enough with Nullable or Nullable arrays to know if there is a specific method, but it should be very easy to use the above in a list comprehension, and replace "null" values (i.e. where `hasvalue` is false) with an identifier of your choice, e.g. NaN, so that you could write the table.

Comment: documentation of NullableArrays is pretty good https://github.com/JuliaStats/NullableArrays.jl

Comment: Awesome, I'll look into that tonight!

Comment: Is `hasvalue` a function in julia or one you created? Anytime I try `a.hasvalue` like you suggested I get `hasvalue does not exist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look / play a bit with the following:

```julia
julia> using DataFrames
julia> a = [Nullable(0.1), Nullable{Float64}(), Nullable(0.3)];
julia> b = [Nullable{Float64}(), Nullable(2.), Nullable(3.)];
julia> df = DataFrame(Any[a,b], [:a,:b])
3×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b     │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 0.1   │ #NULL │
│ 2   │ #NULL │ 2.0   │
│ 3   │ 0.3   │ 3.0   │

julia> c = [df[x] for x in names(df)];
julia> f(x) = [get(y, "Missing") for y in x];
julia> d = Any[f(x) for x in c]; # "Any" required for dataframes (I think)
julia> df2 = DataFrame(d, names(df))
│ Row │ a         │ b         │
├─────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.1       │ "Missing" │
│ 2   │ "Missing" │ 2.0       │
│ 3   │ 0.3       │ 3.0       │

julia> writetable("/home/tasos/Desktop/output.txt", df2)
```

Note that for each column, if there is even one missing value, your numbers will also be reported inside quotes, because of the mixed array. If you want it to be all integers, you'll have to choose a different default value to "Missing" to denote your missing values (e.g. -1 if you only expect positive numbers).

If you don't like that, then you're probably better off writing your own "writetable" function; it's not that difficult, it's just a case of opening a file and printing what you want per column.

---

Also, to address some of our discussion in the comments:

The nullable type has two fields:

```julia
julia> fieldnames(Nullable)
2-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :hasvalue
 :value
```

Let's create two instances to show what they mean:

```julia
julia> a = Nullable(1, true); b = Nullable(2, false);

julia> a.hasvalue, a.value
(true,1)

julia> b.hasvalue, b.value
(false,2)
```

You can test for nullity explicitly:

```julia
julia> isnull(a)
false

julia> isnull(b)
true

julia> isnull(0), isnull("")
(false, false) # isnull returns false by default if input is not a Nullable Type
```

Or you can use the "get" function to get a Nullable's value. If you don't define an alternative in the case of null, you get a NullException:

```julia
julia> get(a)
1

julia> get(b)
ERROR: NullException()
Stacktrace:
 [1] get(::Nullable{Int64}) at ./nullable.jl:92

julia> get(b, "Null Detected")
"Null Detected"
```

A Nullable instance defined as `Nullable(1, false)` has a `.value` of 1, but this is superfluous as it is declared as `.hasvalue=false` and is therefore effectively null (though you can query the `.value` if you really want to).

A Nullable instance defined as `n = Nullable{Float64}()` will give you a nullable instance with `.hasvalue=false` and a meaningless value, presumably whatever was in memory at that location during instantiation, though interpreted as whatever Type of Nullable you declared (i.e. Float64):

```julia
julia> n = Nullable{Float64}()
Nullable{Float64}()

julia> n.hasvalue, n.value
(false, 6.9015724352651e-310)
```

Comment: You're a genius. I modified the way I did it a bit, I used `f(x) = [get(y, NA) for y in x];` instead of `f(x) = [get(y, "Missing") for y in x];`. This allows me to utilize values of DataArrays.NAtype instead of converting them to strings. One thing I don't get though, is how is the f(x) function working? I don't understand how it is identifying only the #NULL values and converting them to NA or "missing".

Comment: Also, I believe :hasvalue has been changed to :isnull in v0.5 and up. When I run `fieldnames(Nullable)` I get `:isnull :value`

Comment: I'm using the dev version, so it's probably the other way round :) (i.e. isnull has probably been changed to hasvalue). With regard to the previous comment, f(x) performs a standard list comprehension; for each element in an array of nullables, it "gets" the element's value, and replaces any nulls with a default option